# How to pass data from AKSwiftSlideMenu menu to a UIViewController in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios9, akswiftslidemenu

Hey guys I am using AKSwiftSlideMenu for slide menu functionality in project and I wonder if is there a way so that I can change the destination ViewController title when I segue to it from the Menu? I tried this code but is not passing the data to the destination:

```
func slideMenuItemSelectedAtIndex(index: Int32) {
let topViewController : UIViewController = self.navigationController!.topViewController!
print("View Controller is : \(topViewController) \n", terminator: "")
switch(index){
case 0:
    print("Note\n", terminator: "")
    var nextVC = AddSubcategoryVC()
    nextVC.categoryName = "Note"
    self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("AddSubcategoryVC") 
    print("On menu the cat is: \(nextVC.categoryName)")
    break
default:
    print("default\n", terminator: "")
} 
}
```

On the destination viewcontroller I have this variable that is to get the data from the Menu:

```
var categoryName = ""
```

and it is returning 'nil'. I also tried doing this:

```
var categoryName : String!
```

and this:

```
var categoryName = String()
```

all returning 'nil'.

Answer (score 0):

You have created new object of view controller.

Replace this code :

```
var nextVC = AddSubcategoryVC()
nextVC.categoryName = "Note"
self.openViewControllerBasedOnIdentifier("AddSubcategoryVC")
```

with

```
let destViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddSubcategoryVC") as! AddSubcategoryVC
destViewController.categoryName = "Note"// You have to pass your data with view controller witch will open
let topViewController : UIViewController = self.navigationController!.topViewController!

if (topViewController.restorationIdentifier! == destViewController.restorationIdentifier!){
    print("Same VC")
} else {
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(destViewController, animated: true)
}
```